# How to validate server generated token for Agora

Tags: agora.io

I am working on generating token for **agora** using `appId` and `certificate`. I am able to generate the token. But I want to validate the token, what is the `Api` calls, I can make, for checking whether my token is valid or not. 
**Note** : I don't want to use any sdk. I just want plain `REST APIs` calls.

Comment: I dont think there is any RestAPI for token checking for now, guess you can use their web demo for this.

Comment: When implementing tokens, there is no other service to verify the toke. The only way to validate is if the client can successfully connect to the channel.